# Algorithm for finding the set of minimum, bounding $n$-spheres that covers a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Let $P$ be a set of finite points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S$ be a set of $n$-spheres that follows these two properties:

- Each $n$-sphere in $S$ overlaps with at least one of the other $n$-spheres in $S$,
- For all $p \in P$, there exists $s \in S$ with center point $c_s$ and radius $r_s$ such that $\text{distance}(c_s, p) \leq r_s$,

where $\text{distance}(x, y)$ is the Euclidean distance between two points of the same dimension.

Is there an algorithm that can find the most optimal $S$? By optimal, I mean the volume occupied by the union of all the $n$-spheres in $S$ is minimum. If none, at the very least approximates the optimal solution.

For example, if $n = 2$ the following image shows how a set of circles cover a set of two-dimensional points:

[image: Set of circles cover a set of 2d points.]

**Side Note:** If we restrict $|S| = 1$ and $n = 2$, it becomes the [Smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem). In general, if $|S| = 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, it becomes the [Minimal bounding sphere problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere). Both are solvable in worse case linear time.

---

Comment: I think you mean "for all $p \in P$, there exists $s \in S$ such that $d(c_s,p) \leq r_s$".

What is your restriction on $|S|$ ? With no restriction, the set of sphere of radius $0$ and center $p \in P$ solves the problem...

Comment: @MathMax You're right, I have now edited my post. Thank you for mentioning the restriction on $|S|$, I would actually want the n-spheres to overlap with each other, i.e. there should be no n-sphere in $S$ whose points are unique to that n-sphere only, at least one of its point must be in one of the other n-sphere in $S$.